# Silverlight Business Application - File Size

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Looking at the silverlight business application, it seems to add a number of libraries specific to Input Forms and the like.

1. Am I right in saying that creating Complex classes results in these forms being generated automatically?
2. Looking at the file size of the basic Silverlight business application XAP file, it's around 412Kb. Is there a way to reduce that size?

Regards,
Jacques

Comment: Without knowing more about what your application does it's impossible to say whether this is correct or not. Generally a Silverlight application is as large as it needs to be.

Comment: well it's the standard Silverlight Business application, with nothing else in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-zip the XAP file, but that is only a 20% saving generally at best.

Using the PRISM pattern and a modular approach, we managed to get our initial page load down to around 150Kb (the entire app is over 4Mb). The rest of the modules continue to stream down in the background so we get something on-screen very fast.

If you intend to build a large application, PRISM and/or MEF is the way to go. It has an additional learning curve but it results in very modular apps (great for team development/maintenance).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips and tricks to try to make your XAP smaller. Like removing references you don't really use and re-zipping the XAP. Hope it helps!

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/21548.aspx